# Tkinter - How to use option 'foreground' for some text in Entry widget?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, widget, foreground, tkinter-entry

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Punctured Convolution Encoder dan Viterbi Decoder")
root.geometry("1350x655+0+0")

frame_input = LabelFrame(root, text="Input")
frame_input.place(x=20, y=10, width=400, height=200)

# input#
lbl_in = Label(frame_input, text="Input", font=("Arial", 16))
lbl_in.place(x=10, y=20)
bin_in = Entry(frame_input, font=('Gill Sans MT', 16))
bin_in.place(x=130, y=20, width=240)

def klik_proses():
    bin_in.selection_range(1,2)
    bin_in.config(foreground="red")
    bin_in.selection_range(4,5)
    bin_in.config(foreground="red")

btn_proses = Button(frame_input, text="test", width=12, command=klik_proses)
btn_proses.place(x=140, y=100)

root.mainloop()
```

The result is the color of the whole text in entry widget was changed, when I pressed the button.
How can I change color for some text in the entry widget?

e.g:
I enter `123456789` in the entry box, then I want to change text color for number `2` and `5`.
So, there are 2 numbers have red color and the others have black color.

Comment: Entry widgets support only a single foreground color. Text and canvas widgets support multiple colored text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to change the color of only part of the text in an Entry, but it is possible in a Text widget using tags. So I suggest you to create a one line Text widget.

Here is an example:

```
import tkinter as tk

def change_color():
    entry.tag_add('red', '1.1')
    entry.tag_add('red', '1.4')

root = tk.Tk()

entry = tk.Text(root, height=1, width=20)
entry.tag_configure('red', foreground='red') 
entry.bind('<Return>', lambda e: "break")  # prevent newlines
entry.insert('1.0', '123456789')

entry.pack()
tk.Button(root, text='Change color', command=change_color).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

You can find more information about the Text widget on [this website](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text.html) .